# Sending an Email via c#.net SmtpClient doesn't work properly

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp, smtpclient

I have this code, used for sending emails from GMX mail to walla mail.

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("yyy@gmx.com", "yyy@walla.com");
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            client.Port = 25;
            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.EnableSsl = true;
            client.Host = "mail.gmx.com";
            mail.Subject = "A new account was registered: ";
            mail.Body = string.Format("Username: {0}, Password: {1}", textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
            try
            {
                client.Send(mail);

            }
            catch (SmtpException ex)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
```

Whenever I try running that code, I get an exception that I need a secured connection, but I have enabled SSL. What didn't I do properly? Thanks!

Comment: Port 25 isn't the SSL port, you need to find out what port GMail uses for SSL and set it to that.

Comment: I found in this website (http://www.smtp-pop3.com/gmx-settings.html) that the ports can be 587 or 465, but none of them work. It just says that I have to connect in a secured way (Why does it keep telling me? I activated SSL!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned on GMX page you must use port 587 when you use SSL/TLS connection:
https://help.gmx.com/en/applications/pop3.html

```
  SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
  client.Port = 587;
```

I think you should also set the credentials to authentication to the SMTP client using the credentials for your mail account:

```
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
```

Comment: It still doesn't work... It just keep telling me this: SMTP server requires a secured connection, or the user won't be authenticated. The server response was: Authentication required

Comment: Please set the credentials as mentioned in my edit. It must be username and password which you use to login to your mail account that is used as sender. Most of the SMTP servers require authentication to avoid SPAM and unintended clients.

Comment: Do you still get the same error? It seems that now it should work. Maybe you have wrong username or password?

Comment: I changed my server to walla, and now it tells me something like that: Failure sending email. System.IO.IOException : Could not read data from... System.Net.Sockets.SocketException ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate an app-specific password on gmx.net. It requieres to enable 2factor-authentication.

Go to gmx.net > Settings > account > password

Here is the info-text from the website

> Für die Nutzung externer E-Mail-Programme über POP3/IMAP oder die Einbindung Ihres GMX Kalenders/Adressbuchs (mit CalDav bzw. CardDav) in ein externes Programm, können Sie hier Anwendungsspezifische Passwörter erstellen und verwalten.
> Um Anwendungsspezifische Passwörter verwenden zu können, muss die 2-Faktor-Authentifizierung aktiviert sein.